# How to create a custom event in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, powershell, events, event-log, custom-events

How can I create a custom event in Windows OS?

I must be able to create a custom event data containing various parameters.

It might be either using command prompt or PowerShell.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What kind of events you talking about - Windows Event Log?

Comment: yeah. About windows Event Logs only.  Please help me with a solution as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can always record entries into `Application` event log using call to one of overloads of method [EventLog.WriteEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.writeevent?view=netframework-4.7.2). For example this one:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
public void WriteEvent (System.Diagnostics.EventInstance instance, byte[] data, params object[] values);
```

Every .Net Class can be easily automated using Windows PowerShell.

Also there are exist special command for PowerShell - [Write-EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/write-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1):

```
Write-EventLog
     [-LogName] <String>
     [-Source] <String>
     [[-EntryType] <EventLogEntryType>]
     [-Category <Int16>]
     [-EventId] <Int32>
     [-Message] <String>
     [-RawData <Byte[]>]
     [-ComputerName <String>]
     [<CommonParameters>]
```

Mayby you will found it more useful.

In Python there are exist special logger class [NTEventLogHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#nteventloghandler) which write event to Windows Event Log.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, But I would like to know In python, is there any code snippet available for custom event creation using our own custom event data?

Comment: Sorry, but the Python is one of my weakest sides.

Comment: Try to look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#nteventloghandler) class. Maybe it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much alexander for your answers

Comment: I glad that can help you. I've just edited my answer so you can mark it as an answer (if you wish).